# in_array() doesn't return all results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

A database table named `users` has a column `timemarks`.

The `timemark` fields look like this.. `11:00:00, 13:45:00, 17:00:00, 18:25:00` (time-marks vary for each user)

My php script should list the users who have a specified time-mark.

Query: `SELECT * FROM ('users')` (query result is returned to `$users`)

Loop:

> 1. iterate through users
> 2. create array `$timemarks_arr` for each user by splitting timemarks string using `str_getcsv`
> 3. echo users with specified time-mark value

```
foreach ($users as $user): 

   $timemarks_arr = str_getcsv($user->timemarks); //split time-marks by comma and create array

    if (in_array("17:00:00", $timemarks_arr)) //users with specified time-mark
    {                               
        echo $entry->username . "<br />";
    }

endforeach;
```

For some reason it echos only 2 users but there are more with time-mark `17:00:00`. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't match values like `17:00:00`, because there's a leading space.

Try this to strip away all whitespace from the beginning and end of strings:

```
$timemarks_arr = array_map( "trim", str_getcsv($user->timemarks)); //split time-marks by comma and create array
```

Comment: Thank you! The trim seems to work. To avoid any other issues I'm considering to change the `00:00:00` time format to timestamp strings when adding to the database